# Excel C# VSTO - how to know whether a user has changed a formula?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-interop

How can one tell whether a user has changed/edited/deleted/added a formula in an Excel worksheet using C# VSTO?

So far, what I have been thinking about is to attach an event handler which can tell me whether the user is changing a cell. But even this approach is problematic because [existing events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbookbase.sheetchange?view=vsto-2017) relating to user editing cells do not seem to be able to tell you the previous and the new value, so I do not really know if an old formula is being overwritten. What is the right approach to this question?

Answer (score 1):

How about you handle `SheetSelectionChange`, cache the selection values and then when (and if) `SheetChange` is raised you compare the new value(s) with the old.

Comment: That is certainly a solution, but an undesirable one. It will struggle under large size spreadsheets and will require a lot of programming logic. If the event handler would return both a before and after value of the cell, it would be a nice abstraction and probably be greatly optimized. I will mark your answer as the best one if no one can find a better solution.

Comment: I guess you can limit the caching to instances where you only have a single selection... I agree with you though - it would have been much better to have the event arguments populated with both values... I would have liked to have a `IsHandled` flag to prevent the change too.